# How do I resize the application launcher / start menu in Kubuntu 20.10?

Tags: kubuntu, customization, application-switcher, kde5

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.10.

How can I resize the start menu?  Because it is gigantic!

[image: screenshot of application launcher]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are calling a "start menu" is more often referred to as an **application launcher**.

Specifically, you are currently using the default application launcher for KDE which is the [Kickoff application launcher](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff).

I'm not sure that you can easily make changes to the size of the Kickoff application launcher, but you can just use a different launcher that better suits your needs.

Here's a [list of alternative "start menu"](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma_application_launchers) style application launchers for KDE Plasma.

---

To change the launcher:

- Right click on your current launcher and select `Show Alternatives...`
- Next, choose the launcher that you want to use.

**I would suggest using the [Kicker](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kicker) launcher (also called "Application Menu")**.  Kicker has a much smaller footprint than Kickoff (which is non-descriptively called "Application Launcher")

Answer (score 5):

hi in the newest version of Kubuntu 22.04 this is possible by hovering over the edge of the launcher menu and then pressing alt + right button on the mouse. This allows you to resize

Comment: The key to press is different in recent Kubuntu versions. So, there you have to press "Meta key + right button". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I will give an answer limited to the default launcher - "Application Launcher" (kickoff).

---

**UPDATED and simpler solution:**

I have noticed that window rules work well if applied correctly. So, pin the launcher:

[image]

Simply start Windows Rules from the launcher itself, *Add New*, and then *Detect window property*.

[image]

[image]

Then, with the cross-cursor, click the Application Launcher pinned window.

And there, select the first options listed, and also add the *Maximized Horizontally* property, so that the settings look like the following:

[image]

It should work after restart and the other widgets windows should not be affected.

---

***Updated answer with full solution*** - from [here](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/plasma-menu-height.html) - **confirmed to work in Kubuntu 23.04**

Make sure you have the necessary directory (you do if you have manually installed some plasmoid):

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/
```

Make a copy of the kickoff plasmoid into the user location:

```
cp -r /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff ~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/
```

Open the file `~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/FullRepresentation.qml`

After

```
Item {
    id: root
```

edit the lines that start with `Layout.minimumWidth` and `Layout.minimumHeight` so that they look like these:

```
Layout.minimumWidth: Math.round(PlasmaCore.Units.gridUnit * 26 * 1.5)
Layout.maximumWidth: Layout.minimumWidth

Layout.minimumHeight: PlasmaCore.Units.gridUnit * 35
Layout.maximumHeight: Layout.minimumHeight
```

and change `26` for width and `35` for height as needed.

---

Restart Plasma desktop or log out and back to see the changes (if you are already using this plasmoid/widget):

```
killall plasmashell && kstart plasmashell
```

---

Another trick in case the launcher cannot be resized *in X11 session* with the mouse (although it now should be resizable by default in Plasma 5.27.10) : I've noticed that in Wayland this may work. So enter Wayland session and resize there.

Comment: I used to do this by having a script that ran and changed FullRepresentation.qml but that doesn't work anymore for me. The drag handles have been removed AFAICT, if they're there then I can't find them! But, "alt+f3, More..., Configure special window settings", works for me as long as I pin the kickoff menu first, I set a minimum size of 720 (which is 720px) for window class exactly matching "plasmashell plasmashell" (without the quotes). This also sets other popups from plasma at the same size, but that's fine for me so far (it's buggy, sometimes size applies to other popups, sometimes not).

Comment: @pbhj - The window rules solution doesn't work for me in K23.04, but the initial way of making a copy per user of the kickoff folder and changing those 4 lines works perfectly.

Comment: @pbhj - I have updated the answer, focused on window rules. The trick seems to be not to miss any of the needed properties that are automatically detected, and then add a supplementary 'maximize' property. Confirmed to work after restart in 22.04 and 23.10 without affecting other widgets like bluetooth or volume.