# KDE Application Menu too fast

Tags: kde, menu

I've been playing around with KDE lately and I'm still trying to learn how to properly customize it.
There is 1 thing which is kind of annoying me and maybe you have an idea how to figure it out. The Application Menu seems a little bit too fast when placing the cursor on the menus. The submenus appear instantly, not really as per my taste. Is there any way to have a small delay like 0.5 sec before the cascading submenu opens when focusing with the cursor on the respective menu?

Like in the old Classic Start Menu from Windows if you know what I mean.

Comment: KDE Plasma 5.24

Comment: Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: You might try increasing the interval value in `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/Kickoff.qml`. If it works you need to copy the qml file to your home directory as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1431933/29073).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Managed to change the delay by modifying /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kicker/contents/ui/ItemListView.qml under "Timer { id: dialogSpawnTimer "  etc to 500 and I can have a small delay for the first submenu, but the next ones are still too fast. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/fzI131Y) of the result. Now is there any way to have the same delay interval for all submenus?